# How to extract a NumericField from a Document in Lucene 3.6

Tags: lucene

I have created a Lucene index for logging where each log record is a document.  Each document has a timestamp encoded as a NumericField.  Creating the index and querying the index is working fine, the one thing I haven't been able to do is extract the timestamp from the document when I want to display it.  The online Lucene docs say that I need to use a Fieldable to retrieve NumericFields, but I can't find out how to get from a Fieldable to a NumericField.

Can anybody point me at some docs or better yet an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work I think, did you try it?:

```
NumericField num = (NumericField) theFieldable;
```